# How to convert annotation-based into native AspectJ syntax

Tags: java, annotations, aspectj

I have some troubles with aspectj and its syntax. I have something written on a java file and I want to translate it to an .aj file because I think that is easier, but I can't find a tutorial to follow.

This is my code:

```
@Aspect
public class Aspect{

    @Pointcut("@annotation(annotationVariableName)")
    public void annotationPointCutDefinition(Annotation annotationVariableName){
    }

    @Pointcut("execution(* *(..))")
    public void atExecution(){}

    @Around("annotationPointCutDefinition(withTransactionVariableName) && atExecution()")
    public Object aroundAdvice(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint, Annotation annotationVariableName) throws Throwable {
        boolean parameter= annotationVariableName.parameter();
            Object returnObject = null;

            try {
                returnObject = joinPoint.proceed();
            } catch (Throwable throwable) {
                throw throwable;
            }
            return returnObject;
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me with this? Thank you!

Comment: The question is unclear. What about this aspect is not working? What do you mean by "translate into an .aj file"? Do you maybe mean you want to switch from annotation-based @AspectJ syntax to native AspectJ syntax? And what are you expecting to be easier than which alternative? P.S.: What is the point in catching an error and re-throwing it identically and unconditionally?

Comment: Yes, what I want is to stop using annotation based aspectj and start using the native syntax. This code works, but I want the native syntax. Sorry for be unclear with that. Can you help me with this? The try catch is because I have to catch that exception, anyway, this is not exactly what I have, there is a commit and a rollback there.

Comment: Usually you should show the code your are trying to write (native AspectJ syntax in your case) together with possible error messages. Just posting an aspect and saying "please do all the work for me" is not so nice. But this time I did it for you. Please just remember it for next time, okay?

Comment: FYI, I have just changed your question title so as to reflect more clearly what the question is about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made up a little example [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) relating to your comment about transaction management, so as to make the code and its log output a little clearer:

**Annotation:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface Transaction {
  boolean myFlag();
}
```

**Driver application:**

Please note that two methods bear the annotation, one does not.

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

public class Application {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Application application = new Application();
    application.doSomething();
    application.doSomethingElse();
    application.doSomethingWeird();
  }

  @Transaction(myFlag = true)
  public void doSomething() {
    System.out.println("Doing something");
  }

  public void doSomethingElse() {
    System.out.println("Doing something else\n");
  }

  @Transaction(myFlag = false)
  public void doSomethingWeird() {
    System.out.println("Doing something weird");
    throw new RuntimeException("oops");
  }
}
```

**Aspect:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.aspect;

import org.aspectj.lang.SoftException;

import de.scrum_master.app.Transaction;

public aspect TransactionAspect {
  pointcut hasAnnotation(Transaction myAnnotation) : @annotation(myAnnotation);

  pointcut methodExecution() : execution(* *(..));

  Object around(Transaction myAnnotation) : methodExecution() && hasAnnotation(myAnnotation) {
    System.out.println(thisJoinPoint + " -> " + myAnnotation);
    boolean parameter = myAnnotation.myFlag();
    System.out.println("Transaction start");
    try {
      Object result = proceed(myAnnotation);
      System.out.println("Transaction commit\n");
      return result;
    } catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println("Transaction roll-back\n");
      // Native AspectJ advices must not return checked exceptions, only runtime exceptions.
      // So we soften the caught exception, just in case.
      throw new SoftException(e);
    }
  }
}
```

**Console log:**

```
execution(void de.scrum_master.app.Application.doSomething()) -> @de.scrum_master.app.Transaction(myFlag=true)
Transaction start
Doing something
Transaction commit

Doing something else

execution(void de.scrum_master.app.Application.doSomethingWeird()) -> @de.scrum_master.app.Transaction(myFlag=false)
Transaction start
Doing something weird
Transaction roll-back

Exception in thread "main" org.aspectj.lang.SoftException
    at de.scrum_master.app.Application.doSomethingWeird_aroundBody3$advice(Application.java:22)
    at de.scrum_master.app.Application.doSomethingWeird(Application.java:1)
    at de.scrum_master.app.Application.main(Application.java:8)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: oops
    at de.scrum_master.app.Application.doSomethingWeird_aroundBody2(Application.java:23)
    at de.scrum_master.app.Application.doSomethingWeird_aroundBody3$advice(Application.java:17)
    ... 2 more
```

By the way, if you are fine with anonymous pointcuts, there is no need to declare them separately. You can just do it this way:

**Aspect variant with anonymous pointcut:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.aspect;

import org.aspectj.lang.SoftException;

import de.scrum_master.app.Transaction;

public aspect TransactionAspect {
  Object around(Transaction myAnnotation) : execution(* *(..)) && @annotation(myAnnotation) {
    System.out.println(thisJoinPoint + " -> " + myAnnotation);
    boolean parameter = myAnnotation.myFlag();
    System.out.println("Transaction start");
    try {
      Object result = proceed(myAnnotation);
      System.out.println("Transaction commit\n");
      return result;
    } catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println("Transaction roll-back\n");
      // Native AspectJ advices must not return checked exceptions, only runtime exceptions.
      // So we soften the caught exception, just in case.
      throw new SoftException(e);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you!!! This works perfectly! Just one more question: I have an exception which is called BusinessExceptions and is throws in some cases, but when testing I put (expected = BusinessException.class), and the aspect throws another exceptions, so the tests fails. The problem is that I made one module for the aspects, and the one which belongs to the domain (which has BusinessException class defined) has that one as dependency. Is there anyway to throw the same exception type that it received? I'm trying to avoid moving that class to the other module. Thank you!

Comment: This is off-topic and worth its own question. Please accept + upvote this question because it is already answered. Then create a new one and notify me.

Comment: Sorry, I think it had something to do with this one. Once more, thank you!

Comment: I've just posted another question about aspectJ, you may be able to help me with that one to (because is similar). The link is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43374990/call-a-setter-to-a-field-which-is-annotated-with-aspectj). Could you please help me? Thank you!

Comment: I'm sorry! I upvoted it but I forgot to accept it. I've just done it.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I found the following programmer guide useful myself although it's not really a tutorial : https://eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/progguide/index.html.  Click on Pointcuts to get the basics of converting your pointcuts, advice is also covered on that page although it doesn't detail "around" advice but there is an example of that under production aspects

A quick search for a tutorial throws up the following (I haven't used this) :
http://o7planning.org/en/10257/java-aspect-oriented-programming-tutorial-with-aspectj

Comment: Thank you for the links, I'll try to follow them!

Comment: That's a good guide, but it always talks about specific classes (call(void Point.setX(int))), I want to do it with the methods annotated with a specific annotation. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: That site does include annotation handling : https://eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/adk15notebook/annotations-pointcuts-and-advice.html#annotation-patterns.  @Transaction * *(..) would match any method annotated with Transaction with any return type and with any name