# Call a setter to a field which is annotated with AspectJ

Tags: java, aspectj, setter

I want to intercept all assignments to a field which is annotated with MyAnnotation in this case. If it works when the value is assigned with reflction is much better. 
This is what I tried, but it does not run, and I think that something else might be wrong:

```
public privileged aspect MyAnnotationAspect {

    pointcut hasAnnotation(MyAnnotation annotation) : @annotation(annotation);

    pointcut methodExecution() : execution(* *(..));

    Object around(MyAnnotation annotation) : set(String word) && methodExecution() && hasAnnotation(annotation) {
        Object result = null;
        try {
            result = proceed(annotation, "new"); //Just to try I want to assign "new" instead of the variable word
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        }
        return result;
    }

}
```

It says that are too many arguments for the method proceed. Can anyone help me? Thank you!

**EDIT**

Now it throws "Warning:(10, 0) ajc: advice defined in aspects.AnnotationAspect has not been applied [Xlint:adviceDidNotMatch]"

This is my aspect:

```
public aspect AnnotationAspect {

    pointcut hasAnnotation(Annotation annotation) : @annotation(annotation);

    Object around(Annotation annotation, String word) : hasAnnotation(annotation) && set(String *) && args(word) {
        Object result = null;
        System.out.println(thisJoinPoint);
        try {
            result = proceed(annotation, "intercepted");
        } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
            throw ex;
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

This is the annotation:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
public @interface Annotation {
}
```

I have a dummy in order to test it:

```
class DummyEntity{

  @Annotation
  var name: String =_

  def setName(n: String): Unit ={
    name = n
  }
}
```

And this is the test where I'm testing it:

```
public class AnnotationAspectTest {

    private DummyEntity dummyEntity;

    @Before
    public void setUp(){
        dummyEntity = new DummyEntity();
    }

    @Test
    public void testing(){
        dummyEntity.setName("newName");
        Assert.assertEquals("intercepted", dummyEntity.name());
    }
}
```

Comment: In the `proceed` call, remove the argument `annotation`

Comment: If I do that it says that it can't convert String to MyAnnotation

Comment: Try this then `Object around(String word) : set(word) ...`

Comment: Now it says "Syntax error on token ")", "name pattern" expected". I just changed what you said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `methodExecution()` is counter-productive here because you do not want to capture method executions, but field write access. Because `set(..) && execution(..)` are mutually exclusive, this makes no logical sense.

Furthermore, you need to bind the assigned value to a parameter via `args()` in order to be able to modify it.

```java
package de.scrum_master.aspect;

import de.scrum_master.app.MyAnnotation;

public aspect MyAnnotationAspect {
  Object around(MyAnnotation annotation, String word) :
    @annotation(annotation) && set(String *) && args(word)
  {
    System.out.println(thisJoinPoint);
    Object result = null;
    try {
      result = proceed(annotation, "altered value");
    } catch (Throwable ex) {
      throw new RuntimeException(ex);
    }
    return result;
  }
}
```

Comment: With this code it compiles, but it's not intercepting the setter. It doesn't print the system out, so I think is not executed. It should work anytime a value is assigned to the field? I have the field annotated with MyAnnotation. I have your code, what might I be doing wrong?

Comment: It intercepts my setter, I tested it. Maybe your annotation does not have runtime retention, maybe there is a typo in the imported package name or another small detail. Is the member targeted by `set()` not a `String`? Does your IDE tell you anything? The compiler? Any errors, warnings? "Does not work" does not qualify for a good problem description. This is the problem with questions that are not [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)s: An aspect without the class targeted by it does not show the full picture.

Comment: I have everything that you said. I've just found tha the compiler says "Warning:(10, 0) ajc: advice defined in aspects.AnnotationAspect has not been applied [Xlint:adviceDidNotMatch]", do you know what might be happening? The anntation is in the same package that one that is working.

Comment: Yes, the warning says it: The advice never runs because the pointcut does not match anything in your code base. You must have an error or a typo in your pointcut. I repeat: Show me an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or I am out of here and you can solve your problem alone. I like to analyse, not to guess.

Comment: Sorry for that, I've just posted more details in the original question, please tell me if you need anything else. Thank you!

Comment: What language is your `DummyEntity` written in? I have no idea what it will translate into when compiled. What I do know, though, is that it will definitely not be compiled by the AspectJ compiler. Can you just try to write that class in plain Java, please? Then tell me what happens. Another possible problem could be that AspectJ might be set up to compile production classes, but not test classes. That depends on your project setup, though. And how do you compile your aspects and classes anyway? Compile-time weaving from source. Binary aspect weaving into existing classes? Load-time weaving?

Comment: When I change it to Java and run it with maven it worked, but if I run it with IntelliJ it doesn't work. The actual language is Scala, and I have another Aspect which annotates that class and it works, but this one doesn't. I have a maven plugin which integrates Scala with the JVM in order to code in both languages

Comment: If it works with Maven, but not with IDEA, you have a configuration issue. The same is true if it works with Java, but not with Scala code. Probably you need to do binary (class file) post-compile weaving in order to reach the Scala code. I need your full project including build configuration on GitHub as an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in order to inspect that. This is way too complex to solve with the snippets of information you can provide here in your comments. Too many possible sources of error.